# Good way to replace invalid characters in firebase keys?

Tags: firebase

My use case is saving a user's info. When I try to save data to Firebase using the user's email address as a key, Firebase throws the following error:

> Error: Invalid key e@e.ee (cannot contain `.$[]#`)

So, apparently, I cannot index user info by their email. What is the best practice to replace the `.`?

I've had success changing the `.` to a `-` but that won't cut it since some email's have `-`s in the address.

Currently, I'm using

```
var cleanEmail = email.replace('.','`');
```

but there are likely going to be conflicts down the line with this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the email address, replace the dot `.` with a comma `,`. This pattern is best practice.

The comma `,` is *not* an allowable character in email addresses but it *is* allowable in a Firebase key. Symmetrically, the dot `.` *is* an allowable character in email addresses but it is *not* allowable in a Firebase key. So direct substitution will solve your problem. You can index email addresses without looping.

You also have another issue.

```
const cleanEmail = email.replace('.',','); // only replaces first dot
```

will only replace the first dot `.` But email addresses can have multiple dots. To replace all the dots, use a *regular expression*.

```
const cleanEmail = email.replace(/\./g, ','); // replaces all dots
```

Or alternatively, you could also use the `split()` - `join()` pattern to replace all dots.

```
const cleanEmail = email.split('.').join(','); // also replaces all dots
```

Comment: Fun fact: The famous Unix `grep` command stands for "Global Regular Expression Print." [Here's the fascinating story behind its origin.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTfOnGZUZDk)

Answer (score 11):

We've dealt with this issue many times and while on the surface it seems like using an email as a key is a simple solution, it leads to a lot of other issues: having to clean/parse the email so it can actually be used. What if the email changes?

We have found that changing the format of how the data is stored is a better path. Suppose you just need to store one thing, the user name.

```
john@somecompany.com: "John Smith"
```

changing it to

```
randomly_generated_node_name
   email:  "john@somecompany.com"
   first:  "John"
   last:   "Smith"
```

The randomly_generated_node_name is a string that Firebase can generate via childByAutoId, or really any type of reference that is not tied directly to the data.

This offers a lot of flexibility: you can now change the persons last name - say if they get married. Or change their email.  You could add an 'index' child 0, 1, 2 etc that could be used for sorting. The data can be queried for any child data. All because the randomly_generated_node_name is a static reference to the variable child data within the node.

It also allows you to expand the data in the future without altering the existing data. Add address, favorite food, an index for sorting etc.

Edit: a Firebase query for email in ObjC:

```
//references all of the users ordered by email
FQuery *allUsers = [myUsersRef queryOrderedByChild:@"email"];

//ref the user with this email
FQuery *thisSpecificUser = [allUsers queryEqualToValue:@“john@somecompany.com”]; 

//load the user with this email
[thisSpecificUser observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  //do something with this user
}];
```

Comment: Thanks jay. I should have specified better. I'm saving the data like you suggest on the main /users db already. The email as key is for index lookups. So my index/users/email/'some@email.com' is set to the actual user id. Maybe I'll give more thought to how to index via an arraylike format

Comment: Yeah - that just causes all kinds of coding issues. Better to not use the actual email (or any data that may ever change) as a key. You may just want to add an index child to each user node:  index: "0", index: "1" etc in each user. That way you get array like behavior without having to actually use an array (which is a bad idea in general), and you can query for a specific user via their name, email, or index.

Comment: Ah maybe I don't see it yet, but wouldn't I need to loop through all the users until the email I'm looking up is found? I'm using the email as key in the index to have a direct lookup and understand the extra code necessary when a property changes. Am I confused?

Comment: Well, you could loop through them but a simpler solution is to just do a query for the email address. I added an ObjC query example to my answer.

Comment: Appreciate the thoughtfulness jay but that's actually what I'm trying to avoid by having a direct lookup index. That way there's no waiting for anything and we will scale without any noticeable hiccups.

Comment: Ah. Understood. I think there's a tradeoff either way:  The direct access method breaks if an email changes so that has to be accounted for as well as having to parse/handle invalid chars - and it's another user node to deal with.  Versus the query delay. Hmm,  I actually haven't run any time-tests either way - maybe someone has done some tests on the delay differences.

Comment: There's def some confusing overhead going my way but I've got it down to 3 promises in a function and one of them is the firebase function to change the simple login email. Not too bad and reusable. I'd be interested in speed checks especially a graph that grows with users. Maybe firebase already indexes to make their queries as fast as possible and I'm just being superficially clever ha

Comment: The Firebase team officially recommends the indexing pattern @irth describes. So we should consider that best practice. If the email address ever changes, you should add the new email address to the index tree. You can optionally delete the old index (based on the now outdated email address) but you might want to keep it around anyway depending on your business logic and requirements.

Comment: @Mowzer They do? I believe that not using email addresses as a key is more along best practice. Using (for example) a key generated with childByAutoId provides these advantages: it doesn't have to be parsed, is indexable, and if the user changes it, it takes one change instead of reading the old node, writing the new node then deleting the old node.

Comment: This won't help with lookupbyEmail. encoding, hashing and replacing . by , will help.

Comment: @KetanYekale There is no such thing as lookupbyEmal encoding in firebase. Keys are strings and do not support encoding, nor should encoding by used on keys - if you stick with the best practice of childByAutoId, its not needed anyway.

Comment: @KetanYekale To clarify... while you can encode/decode in CODE, it's not something that Firebase does - you have to do it. The use case is still sound; email addresses change and if a users email address changes, every node parent throughout the entire database, read the node, delete the node and re-write the node. If it's simply stored as a child within a parent node, and that parent node (childByAutoId) is stored in the other nodes, you can make one change and it's done. It's a very efficient approach. We started with email keys and quickly discovered it was very inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two major ways to solve this issue:

1. **Encode/Decode function**

Because of the limited set of characters allowed in a Firebase key, a solution is to transform the key into an valid format (**encode**). Then have an inverse function (**decode**) to transform the encoded key back as the original key.

A general encode/decode function might be transforming the original key into bytes, then converting them to a hexadecimal representation. But the size of the key might be an issue.

Let's say you want to store users using the e-mail as key:

```
# path: /users/{email} is User;
/users/alice@email.com: {
    name: "Alice",
    email: "alice@email.com"
}
```

The example above doesn't work because of the dot in the path. So we use the encode function to transform the key into a valid format. `alice@email.com` in hexadecimal is `616c69636540656d61696c2e636f6d`, then:

```
# path: /users/{hex(email)} is User;
/users/616c69636540656d61696c2e636f6d: {
    name: "Alice",
    email: "alice@email.com"
}
```

Any client can access that resource as long as they share the same `hex` function.

Edit: Base64 can also be used to encode/decode the key. May be more efficient than hexadecimals, but there are many different implementations. If clients doesn't share the exact same implementation, then they will not work properly.

Specialized functions (ex. that handles e-mails only) can also be used. But be sure to handle all the edge cases.

2. **Encode function with original key stored**

Doing one way transformation of the key is a lot easier. So, instead of using a decode function, just store the original key in the database.

A good **encode** function for this case is the SHA-256 algorithm. It's a common algorithm with implementations in many platforms. And the chances of collisions are very slim.

The previous example with SHA-256 becomes like this:

```
# path: /users/{sha256(email)} is User;
/users/55bf4952e2308638427d0c28891b31b8cd3a88d1610b81f0a605da25fd9c351a: {
    name: "Alice",
    email: "alice@email.com"
}
```

Any client with the original key (the e-mail) can find this entry, because the encode function is known (it is known). And, even if the key gets bigger, the size of the SHA-256 will always be the same, therefore, guaranteed to be a valid Firebase key.

Comment: This is potentially a general solution to the special use case (i.e., email dots) posed in the OP. I'm curious if the Firebase team endorses this pattern as "best practice?" @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @Mowzer I'm using this same idea in others places now. I'll rewrite the answer to be more general. Would love to hear about potential issues from Firebase team. But so far this has worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following code for converting email to hash and then using the hash as key in firebase

```java
public class HashingUtils {
    public HashingUtils() {
    }

    //generate 256 bits hash using SHA-256
    public String generateHashkeySHA_256(String email){
        String result = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] hash = digest.digest(email.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return byteToHex(hash); // make it printable
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    //generate 160bits hash using SHA-1
    public String generateHashkeySHA_1(String email){
        String result = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            byte[] hash = digest.digest(email.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return byteToHex(hash); // make it printable
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String byteToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            formatter.format("%02x", b);
        }
        String hex = formatter.toString();
        return hex;
    }
}
```

code for adding the user to firebase

```java
public void addUser(User user) {
    Log.d(TAG, "addUser: ");
    DatabaseReference userRef= database.getReference("User");

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmailId())){
       String hashEmailId= hashingUtils.generateHashkeySHA_256(user.getEmailId());
        Log.d(TAG, "addUser: hashEmailId"+hashEmailId);
        userRef.child(hashEmailId).setValue(user);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG,"addUser: empty emailId");
    }
}
```