# In firebase, how to set user details on the basis of their e-mail id's instead of UID or other credentials?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to change some fields in user details that correspond to a certain e-mail id manually.

Currently I have to look in authentication console for the e-mail id corresponding to UID(which is basis of storing user details now) but I don't want to do that.

Another option I thought was storing user details on the basis of their mobile numbers(as it is equally easily recognisible as email-id), but this will make login system on the basis of phone number instead of email-id.

Main problem is **dot** in email-id's that don't let email-id's to store as keys.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904123/good-way-to-replace-invalid-characters-in-firebase-keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, Firebase does not allow in it's key symbols like `.` (dot). There are also other symbols like `$` (dollar sign), `[` (left square bracket), `]` (right square bracket), `#` (hash or pound sign) and `/` (forward slash) that are also forbidden.

So in order to solve your problem, you need to encode the email address like this:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

To achieve this, i recomand you to use the following method:

```
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}
```

And to decode the email, you can use the following method:

```
static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```

Comment: nice approach, but what if an email address has commas(although it's rare as most domain don't allow so) in it, decoded string will be different from original one.

Comment: An email address cannot contain commas, only letters (a-z), numbers, and periods. But if you think that you'll have email addresses which will contain commas, then you are free to replace la dot with another symbol or with `,,` double or triple commas. As you wish.